# Definition of "a topological manifold with corners".

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

How can we define a topological manifold with corners and its corners? Then, do we use "invariance of domain" to define corners, as we really need this theorem in order to define "boundaries of a manifold"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Manifolds with corners are defined similarly to manifolds with boundary. The only difference that in addition to local model space equal to $R^n$, one also allows products $H_{k,n}=(R_+)^k \times R^{n-k}$. Here $R_+=[0,\infty)$. Thus, a topological $n$-manifold with corners is a Hausdorff 2nd countable topological space $X$ equipped with a maximal atlas, whose charts are described below: For every $x\in X$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ homeomorphic to some $H_{k,n}$ via a prescribed homeomorphism $f: U\to H_{n,k}$ (a "chart"); here $k$ depends on $x$. It is a requirement that the transition maps between charts 
$$
h=g\circ f^{-1}: V\subset H_{k,n}\to H_{k,n}
$$
preserve the corners, in the sense that 
$$
h(0\times R^{n-k} \cap V)\subset 0\times R^{n-k}. 
$$
(You do not need this requirement in the case of manifolds with boundary.) 
This defines a stratification of $X$ into $n-k$-dimensional strata $X_k$:
$$
X_k=\{x\in X: f(x)=0\times R^{n-k}\subset H_{n,k}\}
$$ 
for some chart $f$. if $X=X_0$ then $X$ is simply a topological manifold; if $X=X_0\cup X_1$ then $X$ is a manifold with boundary.

See also [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.3518v2.pdf).

Edit: Lastly, you do not need the invariance of domain theorem to define corners. Furthermore, a homeomorphism between two manifolds with corners need not preserve corners. Just think about self-homeomorphism $(R_+)^2\to (R_+)^2$: They need not set the origin to itself. However, the category of manifolds with corners has its own notion of isomorphisms; such isomorphisms will preserve corners by definition.

Answer (score 31):

Actually, a topological manifold with corners is identical to a topological manifold with boundary.  A typical definition of an $n$-dimensional *topological manifold with boundary* is a second-countable (or paracompact, take your pick) Hausdorff space in which each point has a neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of $[0,\infty) \times \mathbb R^{n-1}$. The natural way to define a *topological manifold with corners* would be to replace the "model space" by $[0,\infty)^k \times \mathbb R^{n-k}$ for some $1\le k \le n$.  However, it turns out that any two such model spaces are homeomorphic. Thus corner points and boundary points are not topologically distinguishable from each other.

The only time it makes sense to distinguish between "manifolds with corners" and "manifolds with boundary" is if a smooth structure is involved. Because $[0,\infty) \times \mathbb R^{n-1}$ is not *diffeomorphic* to $[0,\infty)^k \times \mathbb R^{n-k}$ when $k>1$, the smooth compatibility condition for charts depends on which model space is used, and a "smooth manifold with corners" need not be a "smooth manifold with boundary."

Comment: To the contrary to your claim even in the setting of topological manifolds, it is sometimes useful to treat manifolds with corners as stratified spaces rather than merely manifolds with boundary. Among most important examples which come to mind are Borel-Serre bordification and Davis trick.

Comment: OK. In that case the stratification is an additional piece of information, not determined by the topology alone.

Comment: "However, it turns out that any two such model spaces are homeomorphic." Why?